# Is there an R function that outputs corresponding regex patterns found inside an inputted character vector?

Tags: r, regex, string

With R, consider I have the following character vector:

```
input_vector <- c("123abc", "456efg", "hij789", "lmn000")
```

I would like to know if there is an existing function, say, `myfunc()`, that would ouputs the regex patterns behind my vector. In other words:

```
myfunc(input_vector)

> [1] "[:digit:]{3}[:alpha:]{3}" "[:digit:]{3}[:alpha:]{3}" "[:alpha:]{3}[:digit:]{3}" 
  [4] "[:alpha:]{3}[:digit:]{3}"
```

**[EDIT]**: Following @Allan Cameron first response, I add that my ultimate goal is to detect all possible `[:digit:]-[:alpha:]` patterns found inside an arbitrarily long character vector that I know its elements theoretically embeds `[:digit:]` or `[:alpha:]` characters only (this is a simplification but a solution of this problem is largely enough). Say:

```
input_vector2 <- 1000L
input_vector2 <- c("123abc", "456efg", ..., "zz6ab8") # this line is illustrative, just imagine a 1000L character vector
```

What I really want, if possible, is a function that returns element-wise [:digit:]-[:alpha:] structures of `input_vector2`:

```
myfunc(input_vector2)

> [1] "[:digit:]{3}[:alpha:]{3}" # (or any way to tell there is three consecutive [:digit:] then three consecutive [:alpha:])
  [2] "[:digit:]{3}[:alpha:]{3}"
  ...
  [1000] "[:alpha:]{2}[:digit:][:alpha:]{2}[:digit:]"
```

Thanks in all cases!
Daniel

I tried to search for an existing Stack overflow related subjects but couldn't find a solution nor a hint towards the solution.

I can't think of any R function/tricks I know that could get me the desired output mentioned above.

Comment: The problem is that these are not unique regexes to match your strings. The strings `".+"` or `"^.{6}$"` or `"(\\d\\d\\d\\D\\D\\D)|(\\D\\D\\D\\d\\d\\d)"` would be valid matches for _any_ of your strings. There is no unique solution, and the simplest solutions are likely to be useless. For example, `myfunc <- function(x) rep('.?', length(x))` technically gives you a solution, but it is trivial. You need to specify your problem more completely. What exact format do you want in different circumstances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) Base R** If it is just a mater of matching alphas or digits then split each string into single characters, replace alphas and digits each with a pattern, run `rle` to get the run lengths, put it back together and remove `{1}` occurrences.  No packages are used.

```
input_vector |>
  strsplit("") |>
  lapply(\(x) sub("^[[:alpha:]]$", "[[:alpha:]]", x)) |>
  lapply(\(x) sub("^[[:digit:]]$", "[[:digit:]]", x)) |>
  lapply(rle) |>
  sapply(\(x) with(x, sprintf("%s{%d}", values, lengths)) |>
     paste(collapse = "")) |>
  gsub("{1}", "", x = _, fixed = TRUE)
```

giving

```
[1] "[[:digit:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]{3}" "[[:digit:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]{3}"
[3] "[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digit:]]{3}" "[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digit:]]{3}"
```

**2) gsubfn** Create a function `gen_pat` which given an alpha or digit string in the respective arguments output the pattern that matches it and then call it repeatedly from `gsubfn`.  The two capture groups are passed to `gen_pat` via `alpha` and `digit` arguments and the regular expression ensures that only one of them has non-zero number of characters.

```
library(gsubfn)

gen_pat <- function(alpha, digit) {
  if (nzchar(alpha)) sprintf("[[:alpha:]]{%d}", nchar(alpha))
  else sprintf("[[:digit:]]{%d}", nchar(digit))
}

input_vector |>
  gsubfn("([[:alpha:]]+)|([[:digit:]]+)", gen_pat, x = _) |>
  gsub("{1}", "", x = _, fixed = TRUE)
```

### Note

Input from question

```
input_vector <- c("123abc", "456efg", "hij789", "lmn000")
```

Answer (score 2):

With a for loop:

```
foobar <- function(string) {
  isdig <- \(x) grepl("[0-9]", x)
  dig   <- logical(0L)
  len   <- integer(0L) 
  for (i in seq_len(nchar(string))) {
    x <- substr(string, i, i)
    if (i == 1L || xor(isdig(x), dig[length(dig)])) {
      len <- c(len, 1L)
      dig <- c(dig, isdig(x))
    } else {
      len[length(len)] <- len[length(len)] + 1L
    }
  }
  dig <- ifelse(dig, "[:digit:]{%d}", "[:alpha:]{%d}")
  do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = paste(dig, collapse = ""), as.list(len)))
}

input_vector <- c("123abc", "456efg", "hij789", "lmn000", "123abc", "456efg", "zz6ab8")
sapply(input_vector, foobar)
#                                             123abc                                             456efg 
#                         "[:digit:]{3}[:alpha:]{3}"                         "[:digit:]{3}[:alpha:]{3}" 
#                                             hij789                                             lmn000 
#                         "[:alpha:]{3}[:digit:]{3}"                         "[:alpha:]{3}[:digit:]{3}" 
#                                             123abc                                             456efg 
#                         "[:digit:]{3}[:alpha:]{3}"                         "[:digit:]{3}[:alpha:]{3}" 
#                                             zz6ab8 
# "[:alpha:]{2}[:digit:]{1}[:alpha:]{2}[:digit:]{1}"
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, you can use `strsplit` to split strings by patterns, and then identify the patterns using `nchar` to count the occurrences, e.g.,

```
sapply(
  strsplit(input_vector,
    "(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)",
    perl = TRUE
  ), \(s) {
    paste0(
      sprintf(
        "[[:%s:]]{%i}",
        c("alpha", "digital")[1 + grepl("\\d+", s)],
        nchar(s)
      ),
      collapse = ""
    )
  }
)
```

which gives

```
1] "[[:digital:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]{3}" "[[:digital:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]{3}"
[3] "[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digital:]]{3}" "[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digital:]]{3}"
```